# ASP.net or Windows Forms Bar Code Scanner

Tags: .net

I have a barcode scanner that emulates a keyboard.  So, if I open notepad and I scan a card it automatically inputs into notepad and presses Enter.   If i open up my application and put the cursor in the textbox it works great also.  However, the user may want to browse the web while people scan into the system at his desk.

How can I set it up where the barcode scanner goes directly into an application?

App must run in the background(i'm assuming)

Comment: This sounds like it would be how the scanner is installed, as most emulate a keyboard, so Windows will send those messages to the current application.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have the barcode scanner not set up as a keyboard wedge, but the program to connect and read directly from it such as a standard HID device.

It if is being used as a keyboard wedge, then focus must remain in the text box that the content should be scanned into.

http://www.lvr.com/hidpage.htm has some decent information about writing your own HID interface.  I have used a variation of this in the past to use a symbol scanner to interact with a winform application.  I do not think you could implement this using web technology unless you use some active-x components.

Answer (score 0):

You must set up a Global Hook or Windows Hook to do this.